# Can I ask google search to re-index my apps' play store listing?

Tags: google-play, google-search, google-search-console

I recently updated the store listing for my app on play store (name of the app and description). The changes are reflected in the play store. But when I search for my app in Google Search, the meta-title and meta-description are old title and description.

Since the new description and title are not picked up (indexed/crawled) by google search, I believe it's not picking up the new keywords I put in.

Is it something to do with URL canonicalization? If so, how can google search return results with the latest changes?

Answer (score 0):

Google search re-indexes all web pages (including the Play Store) at different frequencies. The re-index will occur eventually, you just have to wait.